# Правильное составление предложения

Tags: грамотная-речь, глаголы, времена

Можно ли так говорить: "я был познакомился с девушкой". Глагол "был" можно употреблять в данном случае?

Comment: Правильно:  Я **бы** познакомился.  "Бы" здесь совершенно не глагол.

Comment: Имеется ввиду прошедшее время)

Comment: В прошедшем времени - просто "я познакомился с девушкой" (как то раз). Или: "Бывало, знакомился и я с девушками".

Answer (score 2):

Познакомился - простое глагольное сказуемое в форме глагола прошедшего времени, на прошедшее время указывает суффикс прошедшего времени -л-.Здесь не нужен глагол был.

Глагольная связка был употребляется в составном именном сказуемом: Он был хорошим учеником.(Наст. время: Он хороший ученик). Он был  молодым и сильным. Я был молод. Нужны были книги.

Answer (score 2):

**Я познакомился с девушкой.**

В русском языке глагол **совершенного вида** *познакомился* обозначает **законченное действие**, поэтому вспомогательный глагол *был* (как в английском языке) здесь не требуется.